# Regex: keep same pattern found multiple times in same line

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is it possible with notepad++ (or maybe from linux bash shell) to create multiple lines from a pattern found , as many times as the pattern is found?
The pattern in this case is val=[0-9]+

For example:

input line: 
`other stuff,val=3234,val=123,val=678`

output lines:

```
val=3234
val=123
val=678
```

Comment: Yes, you can put it in a capturing group, replace with `$1\n` and that should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slightly improve on @vs97 answer by using the regex

```
[^,]*,(val=\d+)
```

and replacing with `\1\n`. This will deal with getting rid of the 'other stuff` without requiring a separate replace operation.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3Y1tkC/1)

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Enable Regular Expression.

Regex explanation: `,(val=\d+)` - match comma and then `val=[0-9]` recurring, with `val=\d+` captured as **Group 1**. In Notepad++, you can access Group 1 contents as **\1**.

So replace your regex result with newline (**\n**) + Group 1 contents (**\1**).

[image]

**Result:**

```
other stuff
val=3234
val=123
val=678
```

If you want `other stuff` to be removed, then you first need to capture it via following regex: `^[^,]+` and Replace with nothing, and then run regex `,(val=\d+)` and replace with `\1\n`. Then result will be:

```
val=3234
val=123
val=678
```